# start FormDialog from saved conversation

Tags: botframework

This somewhat builds on the proactive usecase examples and I have a simple use case:

1. When a user initiates conversation with the bot - bot saves the activity object
2. An API endpoint exists
3. When the api endpoint is triggered
4. the activity object is retrieved, from is swapped with to - and a message is sent back to the user via SendToConversationAsync.

Rather than just replay back an activity message to the user, is it possible to kick of a FormDialog by somehow retrieving or recreating the iDialogue object so that context.Call can be triggered with the appropriate form?

I've tried using various things but nothing shows up on the user side; specifically, I tried

```
await Conversation.SendAsync(message, () => new MakeSomeFormDialog());
```

and

```
Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(SomeForm.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart));
```

and the interactive example -

```
Task Interactive(IDialog form) where T : class
```

however, I think the interactive example, but I think this is attempting to post to bot?

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: updated the question - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be fairly straight forward. I asked for help on the rep and I was pointed in the correct direction.

Proactive bot examples that cover this case are here https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botFramework-proactiveMessages

specifically this bit of code https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botFramework-proactiveMessages/blob/master/csharp/startNewDialogWithPrompt/ConversationStarter.cs#L31

public class ConversationStarter
    {
        //Note: Of course you don't want this here. Eventually you will need to save this in some table
        //Having this here as static variable means we can only remember one user :)
        public static string resumptionCookie;

```
    //This will interrupt the conversation and send the user to SurveyDialog, then wait until that's done 
    public static async Task Resume()
    {
        var message = ResumptionCookie.GZipDeserialize(resumptionCookie).GetMessage();
        var client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl));


        using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
        {
            var botData = scope.Resolve<IBotData>();
            await botData.LoadAsync(CancellationToken.None);
            var stack = scope.Resolve<IDialogStack>();

            //interrupt the stack
            var dialog =new SurveyDialog();
            stack.Call(dialog.Void<object, IMessageActivity>(), null);
            await stack.PollAsync(CancellationToken.None);

            //flush dialog stack
            await botData.FlushAsync(CancellationToken.None);

        }
    }
}
```

gets you the context back and interrupt with another dialog (which can be a form dialog)